# UDOO board- SD Card Partition

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have a UDOO Quad board loaded with Ubuntu 12.04. Before loading ubuntu I did not partition the SD card (8GB). Now if I want to Install Hydro ROS, will I be able to partition it without erasing ubuntu from the SD Card?

Or can I put in ROS without partitioning?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143121/udoo-board--sd-card-partition/) by [AMehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/13691/amehra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2014-03-21**:
Acctually  ROS just like the software not really OS, if you install it , it will be stored in ubuntu file system, you dont need divide partition

**Comment by [AMehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/13691/amehra/) on 2014-03-22**:
Hi domikilo, thanks! Thats all I wanted confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to expand the root file system, if that is what you are asking.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2